# How to get input from javascript without stutters between changing keys pressed

Tags: javascript, performance, input

I am currently doing this for input handling:

```
var upKey = false;
var downKey = false;
var leftKey = false;
var rightKey = false;

var sqrt2over2 = 0.707106781;
var MoveSpeed = 20.0;
var Horizontal = false;
var Vertical = false;

document.onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.which == 87)
    {
        Vertical = false;
        upKey = false;
    }
    if(e.which == 83)
    {
        Vertical = false;
        downKey = false;
    }
    if(e.which == 65)
    {
        Horizontal = false;
        leftKey = false;
    }
    if(e.which == 68)
    {
        Horizontal = false;
        rightKey = false;
    }
}

document.onkeydown=function(e){
    //Up arrow key
    if(e.which == 87) upKey = true;
    //Down arrow key
    if(e.which == 83) downKey = true;
    //Left arrow key
    if(e.which == 65) leftKey = true;
    //Right arrow key
    if(e.which == 68) rightKey = true;

    var diagonals = Vertical && Horizontal;
    if(downKey)
    { 
        Vertical = true;
        moveY -= diagonals ? MoveSpeed * sqrt2over2: MoveSpeed;
    }
    if(upKey)
    {
        Vertical = true;
        moveY += diagonals ? MoveSpeed * sqrt2over2: MoveSpeed;
    }
    if(rightKey)
    {
        Horizontal = true;
        moveX -= diagonals ? MoveSpeed * sqrt2over2: MoveSpeed;
    }
    if(leftKey)
    {
        Horizontal = true;
        moveX += diagonals ? MoveSpeed * sqrt2over2: MoveSpeed;
    }   
}
```

I need to have this work so that the screen doesn't pause at all when you press another direction or multiple directions. Currently there is a bit of a pause. Is there a setting to turn off this pause or is there another approach to pooling and responding to input which circumvents this dilemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the pause is due to key repeat rate. Take a look at this question / answers: [remove key press delay in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691461/remove-key-press-delay-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the operating system's key repeat as the 'tick' for moving. Instead of this you should use `setInterval` to create your own tick for moving, and then monitor keydown / keyup to change the direction of movement.