# javascript delay between function calls for each index in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

### The Goal:

- Execute logic on each element in array.
- Wait `X` ms in between next execution.
- `mouseover(#slider)` pauses delay - If delay = 1000ms, and 300ms had passed, `mouseout(#slider)` would trigger resume counting down the remaining 700ms delay.
- After execution on last element, loop back to do it again - forever.

**Here's a visual explanation:**

```
var = s Array(1,2,3)

var x = s[1];   //get first element   
console.log(x); //do something to it
wait();         //START wait timer 1000ms

//------------> timer : 300ms
//------------> user  : mouseover (#slider) : pause timer
//------------> user  : waited 5000ms
//------------> user  : mouseout  (#slider) : resume timer
//------------> timer : 300ms --> still 700ms to go!
//------------> timer : 500ms
//------------> user  : mouseover (#slider) : pause timer
//------------> user  : waited 10000ms
//------------> user  : mouseout  (#slider) : resume timer
//------------> timer : 500ms --> still 500ms to go!

var x = s[2];   //get second element   
console.log(x); //do something to it
wait();         //START wait timer 1000ms

//------------> timer : 200ms
//------------> user  : mouseover (#slider) : pause timer
//------------> user  : onclick   (.slideButton1) : change index of array and clear timer
//------------> user  : waited 6000ms
//------------> user  : mouseout  (#slider) : resume timer
//------------> timer : 0ms --> still 1000ms to go!

var x = s[1];   //get first element   ( index was changed by clicking button )
console.log(x); //do something to it
wait();         //START wait timer 1000ms

// ... s[2] ... s[3] ...
//theres nothing else in the array, lets start back from s[1] again!
```

### Solutions:

**jQuery:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zGd8a/8/

This solution came from a related [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002674/jquery-each-index-when-passed-self). The official source of this plugin can be found [**here**](http://roxon.in/scripts/fademe_jquery_plugin/).

**Native JS:**

http://jsfiddle.net/SyTFZ/4/

This **[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926531/javascript-recursive-loop-through-array-with-delay-between-elements#12926811)** by **[Aadit M Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783743/aadit-m-shah)** was really helpful. He also goes into detail about **Delta Timing** and how it can be useful in similar cases.

### New Goal:

Abstract up either of these methods to allow use for other things.

Comment: Completed your slider: http://jsfiddle.net/SyTFZ/

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain what's happening soon.

Comment: Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/SyTFZ/1/

Comment: I updated my answer. The latest version of the demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SyTFZ/4/

Comment: @AaditMShah This is a really great solution. Your level of effort to answer this question is awsome. Porting this logic for other things has **lots of potential.** I will definatly spend a chunk of time disecting this tomorow.

Comment: @AaditMShah started a bounty to get these answers more attention.

Comment: Is this an actual question? It seems more like a work-for-free assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I don't use jquery and in all probability I have no clue as to what you're trying to achieve. However from what I understand I think you should do something like this:

```
var i = 0;
var t = this;

var timer = new DeltaTimer(function (time) {
    // your animation
    var x = t.s[i];
    x.delay("1000").css("background-color", "#FAAF16");
    delete t.s[i];
    t.s.push(x);
    // increment i
    i++;
}, 1000);

var start = timer.start();
```

You will notice here that I've used a constructor called `DeltaTimer`. This constructor is defined in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2056987). It allows you to control your animations precisely using `start` and `stop` functions. The `render` function which is passed is given a `time` argument which is a `Date`. The expression `time - start` gives the exact time when the function was called (e.g. `4`, `1000`, `2000`, ...).

The advantage of using `DeltaTimer` over `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is:

1. It [corrects itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing). This means that animations are smoother and there's less lag.
2. The animation can be controlled by starting and stopping the timer.
3. The exact time of the function call is passed to the function. This helps in keeping track of which frame is being rendered, where should the sprite be rendered, etc.
4. The logic for animation is separated from the logic of timing control. Thus code is more cohesive and more loosely coupled.

You can read my other answers regarding delta timing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11521360/783743), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624239/783743) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11490193/783743).

**Edit 1:** That's actually pretty simple. We simply shift out the first element of the array, process it and then push it back at the end. Here's the logic:

```
function loopIterate(array, callback, interval) {
    var timer = new DeltaTimer(function (time) {
        var element = array.shift();
        callback(element, time - start);
        array.push(element);
    }, interval);

    var start = timer.start();
};
```

Now we can create an array and loop through it as follows:

```
var body = document.body;

loopIterate([1, 2, 3], function (element, time) {
    body.innerHTML += element + ": " + time + "<br/>";
}, 1000);
```

You can see the output here: http://jsfiddle.net/aGQfr/

**Edit 2:** Oops, I found a problem. From what I understand you want to process the next element a certain amount of time *after* the current element is *finished* processing. My delta timing script doesn't do that. It only executes functions at fixed intervals of time.

So, you don't need delta timing at all. You need to call `setTimeout` after each element has been processed:

```
function loopIterate(array, callback, interval) {
    var start = + new Date;
    process();

    function process() {
        var element = array.shift();
        callback(element, new Date - start);
        array.push(element);

        setTimeout(process, interval);
    }
};
```

After that just create an array and loop through it as follows:

```
loopIterate([1, 2, 3], function (element, time) {
    alert(element);
}, 1000);
```

You can see the demo here (note that your browser may not like it): http://jsfiddle.net/aGQfr/1/

**Edit 3:** You may also combined methods one and two so that you have a script which:

1. Waits for the processing to finish before adding the next element to process to the event queue.
2. Can be controlled using a `start` and `stop` function.
3. Gives the exact time the callback is called.
4. Separates processing from timing control.

We'll create a constructor function called `LoopIterator` which returns an iterator object with `start` and `stop` methods:

```
function LoopIterator(array, callback, interval) {
    var start, iterate, timeout;

    this.start = function () {
        if (!iterate) {
            start = + new Date;
            iterate = true;
            loop();
        }
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        if (iterate) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            iterate = false;
        }
    };

    function loop() {
        var element = array.shift();
        callback(element, new Date - start);
        array.push(element);

        if (iterate) timeout = setTimeout(loop, interval);
    }
}
```

Now we can create and start a new iterator as follows:

```
var iterator = new LoopIterator([1, 2, 3], function (element, time) {
    alert(element);
}, 3000);

iterator.start();
```

If you wish you may even stop and start the iterator when the mouse moves over an element or out of an element respectively:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
div.addEventListener("mouseout", iterator.start, false);
div.addEventListener("mouseover", iterator.stop, false);
```

When stopped the iterator's state is preserved and when started again it continues from where it left off.

You may see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/PEcUG/

**Edit 4:** So you want to create a simple slider? Let's start with the HTML, then the CSS and then the JavaScript.

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
```

We have a `div` element with a class called `slider` (because there may be more than one slider on the page). Each slider has zero or more `div` elements with the class `slide`. Each slide may have arbitrary content. The slider will also have buttons, but we don't include this in the HTML as it will be generated automatically by JavaScript. No redundancy. Also note that none of the slides are manually numbered. Everything is handled by JavaScript.

**The CSS:**

```
.slide {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.25em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    display: none;
    padding: 1em;
}

.slider-button {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.25em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    height: 1.25em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    width: 1.25em;
}
```

You may supply arbitrary CSS to suit your taste. An important point however is that `.slide` must have `display: none;` because the slides must initially be hidden. Also `.slider-button` must have `float: right;`. This is important as elements floated to the right have their order reversed. Thus the first button is actually the last button. This must be handled correctly by JavaScript so don't change it unless you know what you're doing.

**The JavaScript:**

Alright, I'll explain this bottom up:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slider");
    var length = sliders.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        new Slider(sliders[i], 2000);
}, false);
```

Here `Slider` is a constructor function which initializes and starts the slider element it passed. It accepts the time interval between two slides as the second argument. Here's the code for `Slider`:

```
function Slider(slider, interval) {
    var slides = slider.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    var iterate, start, timeout, delay = interval;
    slides = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    var buttons = [], numbers = [], goto = [];
    var length = slides.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var button = document.createElement("div");
        button.setAttribute("class", "slider-button");
        slider.appendChild(button);
        buttons.unshift(button);
        numbers.push(i + 1);

        var handler = getHandler(length - i);
        button.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
        goto.unshift(handler);
    }

    this.goto = function (index) {
        var gotoSlide = goto[index];
        if (typeof gotoSlide === "function")
            gotoSlide();
    };

    slider.addEventListener("mouseover", stop, false);
    slider.addEventListener("mouseout", start, false);

    this.start = start;
    this.stop = stop;

    showSlide();
    start();

    function start() {
        if (!iterate) {
            iterate = true;
            start = + new Date;
            timeout = setTimeout(loop, delay);
        }
    }

    function stop() {
        if (iterate) {
            iterate = false;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            delay = interval - new Date + start;
        }
    }

    function loop() {
        hideSlide();
        slideSlider();
        showSlide();

        if (iterate) {
            start = + new Date;
            timeout = setTimeout(loop, interval);
        }
    }

    function hideSlide() {
        slides[0].style.display = "none";
        buttons[0].style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
    }

    function slideSlider() {
        slides.push(slides.shift());
        buttons.push(buttons.shift());
        numbers.push(numbers.shift());
    }

    function showSlide() {
        slides[0].style.display = "block";
        buttons[0].style.backgroundColor = "#FAAF16";
    }

    function getHandler(number) {
        return function () {
            hideSlide();
            while (numbers[0] !== number) slideSlider();
            showSlide();
        };
    }
}
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory. Every instance of `Slider` has a `start`, `stop` and `goto` method for finer control. The `goto` method takes a slide index number. For `n` slides the indices range from `0` to `n - 1`. That's it.

The demo of the slider is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SyTFZ/4/

Comment: Does this only work for animations? I am looking for a timer that will work for any logic. Please see edits, I hope I have made this more clear.

Comment: It works for absolutely anything. It's just like `setInterval`, only better.

Comment: Please see second edits, I really tried to breakdown what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I edited my answer and I added a demo. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thankyou! This looks like it's doing exactly what I need, I'll work it into my code tomorow and give you an update!

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer if you're interested. My first update executes the function at intervals `0`, `1000`, `2000`, etc. My second update executes the function at `0`, then waits till it's finished processing, then executes the function after `1000 ms`, then waits again, etc. You decide which one you wish to use.

Comment: This is absolutely awsome and does exactly what I need. For *bonus* how would I go about pausing during logic based on a condition. For example, say mouseover() some element, the script pauses and resumes when mouseleave()?

Comment: What's the context? Are you using the code from my first edit or my second edit?

Comment: See the following demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PEcUG/

Comment: The iterator starts automatically. If you move it into the pink box then it stops. If you move it out then it starts from where it left off. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thankyou again, this was extremely helpful and really broke down what was going on. I sent you an email to follow up under your public address found on http://en.gravatar.com/aaditmshah

Comment: I think I should update my answer to explain the code that I linked to in my comments.

Comment: I found a slight bug in the code by changing the logic aorund a little. Rather than using alert(element); try using $('body').append(element); Now use the mouse to go on and off the div rapidly. The logic fires immediatly after mouseout. What you will see elements rapidly append to the body.

Comment: `div.addEventListener("mouseout", iterator.start, false);` is problematic.  It should probably be `div.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {iterator.start()}, false);` to allow the `this` pointer to be set to the right instance in your methods.  Your jsFiddle appears to work, but I think that's more luck because of a closure or accidental globals than careful object design.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm going to spin up a jsfiddle and encapsulate this the way im using it in the class when I get home.

Comment: @jfriend00 - You could always `bind` the correct `this` pointer. Instead of passing `function () {iterator.start();}` you may pass `iterator.start.bind(iterator)`. Similarly for `stop`. That should solve your problem more elegantly.

Comment: @AaditMShah - You could use `bind()`, but then you'd need a shim for older browsers like IE8.  Not sure why that complication is better than just using a couple anonymous functions to solve the problem unless you already have the shim installed.

Comment: @AaditMShah Here is a current working implimentation less the features you have put so much effort in. I am having trouble incooperating them into this: http://jsfiddle.net/9FvJw/

Comment: @jfriend00 - Anything that get's the job done.

Comment: @DanKanze - Your slider is working for me. What else needs to be done?

Comment: @AaditMShah Per the http://jsfiddle.net/9FvJw/ I've made significant revisions to the question but only better explain the need. I believe it is in it's final form and is much clearer to understand. The remaining need is outlined at the bottom, although you've made significant strides to complete this already. I am having difficulty working the solution you've provided outlined in the `What I'm missing` section into my class.

Answer (score 7):

OK, now that you've completely simplified the question, here's a generic array iterator function that puts a delay between the iteration of each element of the array and it cycles forever until the callback function returns `false`:

```
function iterateArrayWithDelay(arr, delay, fn) {
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        // protect against empty array
        if (!arr.length) {
            return;
        }

        // see if we need to wrap the index
        if (index >= arr.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        // call the callback
        if (fn(arr[index], arr, index) === false) {
            // stop iterating
            return;
        }

        ++index;

        // schedule next iteration
        setTimeout(next, delay);
    }
    // start the iteration
    next();
}
```

And, for your example, you would use it like this:

```
iterateArrayWithDelay(s, 1000, myFunction);
```

Where you define `myFunction` to be a callback function that processes each element.  The callback is passed three items:

```
myFunction(item, array, i){
    // your code here to process item
}
```

---

`.delay()` only works with jQuery methods that use the animation queue.  In your code example, the `.delay('1000')` isn't doing anything since there are no jQuery animation methods after it on the same object.

As for memory leaks, it's hard to follow the overall context of what you're doing because we can't see the lifetime of the object represented by `this` and its properties.  This sequence looks pretty odd:

```
var x = t.s[i];
...
delete t.s[i];
t.s.push(x);
```

In particular, I don't see how the `delete` statement is actually doing anything because you still have a reference to the contents in `x` so nothing will be garbage collected.  Further, `delete` in javascript is used the get rid of an object property, not for freeing up an object or for removing an array element.  To free up an object, you have to get rid of all references to that object (setting them to some other value so they no longer contain the reference or letting them go out of scope).  Thus, since you're never getting rid of the reference to whatever is in `t.s[i]`, nothing is getting freed.

---

Your use of `setTimeout()` is not causing recursion.  When you call `setTimeout()`, it sets a timer and puts a function reference into a data structure that is associated with that timer.  Then, the calling function continues to run and finishes it's execution.  Thus, it's done executing before the setTimeout() fires and calls it again.  So, it's not actually recursion.  It's a bunch of sequential function calls, separated by a time interval and one finishes before the next can run (because javascript is single threaded and because the timer is set for the future).

Comment: I was more worried about if the that setTimeout executes recursively without delay, but it's queing the function in a stack. So for example, `s()` runs 3 times in 3 ms but que's the execution of `s()` at 1001ms,1002ms,1003ms.

Comment: @DanKanze - I added info about the `setTimeout()` and recursion.

Comment: Right, thanks for the update and this is exactly what I don't want. What I need is something to delay the functions of the actions im taking inside the function as described above.

Comment: @DanKanze - we can't help with a better solution without a description of what you're really trying to accomplish.  For anything other than a jQuery animation, you use `setTimeout()` to introduce a time delay.  Because javascript is single threaded and does not let you wait inside the thread of execution, you have to break each chunk of execution into a function that can be called form `setTimeout()`.  I thought that's what you were doing in your code so I'm not sure why you say it's not doing what you want.  Please back up and describe the overall thing you're trying to solve.

Comment: @DanKanze - If we understood what you're really trying to do, I'm sure we could suggest much cleaner code.

Comment: Please see second edits, I really tried to breakdown what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @DanKanze - Now that you've simplified the question and clarified what you're really trying to do, I added a generic array iterator with delay to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Thankyou for your edits these were very helpful. As seen below however, `@AaditMShah` takes this one step further and allows the user the ability to stop start mid delay preserving the counters remaining time. I've updated my example to show the type of fucntionality I would find very desirable.

Comment: @DanKanze - I completely give up here.  You've moved the entire target of your question two separate times now (three different questions have appeared here).  There was nothing in your question about starting/stopping the iteration when I wrote my second full response and I'm done trying to chase your question around.  Maybe next time you write a question, you can actually specify what you're really looking for help with and be complete enough the first time that people have enough info to actually product a finished answer.  Trying to help you had been a very frustrating experience.

Comment: @DanKanze - twice I've written very complete answers to what your question was asking at the time and twice you've changed the question into something else.  That is NOT how you're supposed to use StackOverflow!  Next time, ask a complete initial question, answer any clarifying questions and then if you have a new question after getting answers to that, ask another NEW question.  Don't change the meaning of your question two times AFTER people have put a lot of energy into answer you.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Questions sometimes unfold after you gain knowledge of unknowns. I appreciate the help and I'm sorry to have frustrated you.

Answer (score 1):

The [plugin jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/) can help you getting this effect done with very short code.
There is already an [example with waiting on mouseover](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/examples/pause-cycle-on-hover.html).

I am sure this can be adapted to your use case, too:

```
function noHover() {
   return this.is(':hover') ? this.wait('mouseleave') : this;
}

$('.images').repeat().each($).fadeIn($).wait(1000).wait(noHover).fadeOut($);
```