# jquery each() index when passed self

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access the element index during each iteration of this loop.

```
$('.slide').hide().repeat().each($).fadeIn($).wait(1000, function(){
    //do stuff
}).wait(noHover).fadeOut($);
```

I tried doing something like:

```
$('.slide').hide().repeat().each(i, $).fadeIn($).wait(1000, function(){
    alert(i);
}).wait(noHover).fadeOut($);
```

Clearly I do not understand the right way to do this.

*The plugin extension im using:*
http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/examples/pause-cycle-on-hover.html

Heres a fiddle that breaks this down better:
http://jsfiddle.net/zGd8a/

A solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/zGd8a/8/

Comment: Why are you passing `$`?

Comment: @SLaks see the URL above for details. part of the plugin logic documentation.

Comment: each accept a callback function. What are you tring to do?

Comment: Now what we should do is go there, explore the plugin and return with some info? isn't more 'nice' you build a fiddle for us?

Comment: sure let me spin one up.

Comment: @roXon ok check it out URL in edit above.

Comment: I don't know what exactly that plugin does when [overwriting `$.fn.each`](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/#each), but it looks like bad practice to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zGd8a/1/)**

```
$('.slide').hide().repeat().each($).fadeIn($).wait(1000, function(){
    var idx = $(this).index();  // here you go!
    $('body').append(idx); //here i need access to index number of element
}).wait(noHover).fadeOut($);
```

Comment: this works, which is awsome. just wondering though - why does the index method need to be called? is there a way to instantiate the index of the element by a parameter similar to each(index, obj) without using a method?

Comment: @DanKanze http://jsfiddle.net/zGd8a/3/ With a plugin of mine... ([FadeMe 'FPS'](http://roxon.in/scripts/fademe_jquery_plugin/))

Comment: this looks like its going to do the job. i am just a little caught up when binding this function to "slide buttons". ive worked your code into my class to give a better example of what I am trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/pvvx6/

Comment: @DanKanze http://jsfiddle.net/zGd8a/7/ :) Just added the span buttons generator (for loop) and targeted the parent element and added a click function to spans. :) so simple. And still you can use this only script for multiple sliders and galleries!

Comment: @DanKanze here is an example with multiple galleries and active class for spans! http://jsfiddle.net/zGd8a/8/

Comment: the callback function in the .wait() method also takes parameters:
In your case .repeat()...each($)...wait(...,function(i,nr){});
The i is the indexf from .each($), and the nr is the current iteration from .repeat().
So you don't need $(this).index()

Answer (score 0):

In this case `each` function takes second parameter (callback function) - `$` and does **nothing** with it. You should place your alert in a body of callback function that is second parameter of `each`, not `wait` function. Like this:

```
$('.slide').hide().repeat().each(function(i, element) {
    alert(i);
}).fadeIn($).wait(1000, function(){
    //do stuff
}).wait(noHover).fadeOut($);
```

More information here: http://api.jquery.com/each/