# Precise keydown event on web page with minimal delay

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, keyboard-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove key press delay in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691461/remove-key-press-delay-in-javascript)

I need to catch keydown events with a minimum time delay on a web page. Everything that I determind about this issue last two days is that delay is platform specific in Javascript and that flash has significant delay too. In OS X all browsers has minimum response time for keydown (js) and it is ok for me, but in Windows it is awfull, especially in Firefox. 
So, the last solution was to focus on the flash object and gather KEY_DOWN events from it to js, but as I mention before this approach has also a delay, maybe not constant for different platforms.

My question is next: is it possible to handle keydown events with a minimal delay in all browsers and platforms?

Thanks!

Comment: google event delegation, and read about the W3C event model on quirksmode or some other site. Capturing the keypress event on the document level will be the most performant approach.

Comment: Hey, it is not a duplication! That question covers repeats problem, but not the latency of keydown. Please, make it available again.