# Why huge gap between keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I'm writing an input control function for a small javascript game. There seems to be a significantly longer delay between the first and second `keydown` events than the subsequent events. Consider the following:

```
let lastPress = 0;

const keydownHandler = (event) => {
  console.log(event.keyCode + ', delta time: ' + (Date.now() - lastPress));
  lastPress = Date.now();
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);
```

If I run this and hold the right arrow key down I'll see a listing like this (in formatted version):

| Keycode | Delta time |
| --- | --- |
| 39 | 142129 |
| 39 | 492 |
| 39 | 82 |
| 39 | 87 |
| 39 | 82 |
| 39 | 83 |
| 39 | 82 |
| 39 | 84 |
| 39 | 82 |
| 39 | 86 |

Now, the first delta is obviously huge (since I'm looking at the difference between the previous call to the event handler). What I don't understand is the value 492 ms compared to the 82 - 87 ms on the following calls.

Why is there such a significant gap between the first two events? And is there a way to narrow that gap?

Comment: Keyboard settings?

Comment: Auto-repeat doesn't start until you've held the key down for a little while. There should be a system setting that controls this delay.

Comment: Have you tried using the `input` event, rather than keyboard events? A keyboard event like `keydown` isn't going to work on a touch device anyway.

Comment: To expand @Barmar 's answer, this first-letter delay is implemented intentionally to decrease the probability of duplicating characters while user types a text. There's indeed a system setting just for that in each OS. You could also consider this answer to simulate continuous keydowns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29191638/504474

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I gathered that this is by design. I ended up with the following (sort of similar to the SO post linked in the comments):

```
currentKeys = [];

const findKey = (keyCode) => {
  return currentKeys.indexOf(keyCode);
}

const keydownHandler = (event) => {
  if (findKey(event.keyCode) === -1) {
    currentKeys.push(event.keyCode);
  }
}

const keyupHandler = (event) => {
  const index = findKey(event.keyCode);
  if (index >= 0) {
    currentKeys.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Then, in the game update function I moved the player according to the input.

Comment: You should use a `Set` to track currently pressed keys.

Comment: `const currentKeys = new Set(); currentKeys.add(event.keyCode); currentKeys.has(event.keyCode); currentKeys.delete(event.keyCode);`

Comment: You don't even need the other checks then: you can add the same value again without issues, and attempt to remove a non-present value without issue.

Comment: `const currentKeys = new Set(); const keydownHandler = (event) => { currentKeys.add(event.keyCode) }; const keyupHandler = (event) => { currentKeys.delete(event.keyCode) }`

Comment: Your other code can then iterate over the present values using `currentKeys.keys()` or `currentKeys.values()` (they're equivalent with `Set`).