# setInterval inside another setInterval speeding up over time

Tags: javascript, animation, setinterval

I spent a long time trying to figure out how to animate a symbol on a polyline with the Google Maps API with CSS-style easing functions. I got this to work [with this Gist](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294) and [this Google Maps API example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate). Now I'm trying to **run a `setInterval(myFunc, 10)` every ~5 seconds**. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
function animateCircle(line) {
    var count = 0;
    let refreshRate = 10;
    let countFunc = EasingFunctions.easeInOutCubic;
    let perc = 0

    function moveCircle() {
      count = count < 1 ? (count + 0.005) : 0;

      perc = countFunc(count) * 100 <= 100 ? countFunc(count) * 100 :  countFunc(count) * 100 - 100
      perc = perc >= 0 ? perc : 100 + perc
      perc === 0 ? window.clearInterval(moveCircInterval) : ''
      // console.log(count + " // " + perc)

      var icons = line.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = perc + '%';

      line.set('icons', icons);
    }

    var moveCircInterval = window.setInterval(moveCircle, refreshRate);

    window.setInterval(() => moveCircInterval = window.setInterval(moveCircle, refreshRate), 5000)
  }
```

And a [full JSFiddle to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/ehpot20j/6/).

This code is not great, but *nearly* working. On my end, it speeds over time, especially if you navigate away from the tab and go back.

Comment: Why do you expect something else `setInterval` Registers a function to be called ever n milliseconds? So every 5secs you register another function that should be call every `refreshRate` ms.

Comment: so you think just clear it every 5 seconds, and then reregister it? @t.niese

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709923/why-is-requestanimationframe-better-than-setinterval-or-settimeout

Comment: It is not clear to me what you try to achieve with that construct.

Comment: I'm trying to call moveCircle every 10ms. Then when its done, or when `perc` returns to 0, wait 5 seconds, and start over. @t.niese

Comment: Just a tip:(at least in Chrome, check for other browsers) if you switch on other windows, the animation will be stuck but not the setInterval... so when you'll back to the window with your animation... it will be accelerated with "cumulated" setIntervals and it will be really messed up. Try to convert in setTimeout and stop the call when your window is not focued, then call it when you focus the window again

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your concern correctly we can tweak your code like below:

```
function animateCircle(line) {
    var count = 0;
    let refreshRate = 10;
    let countFunc = EasingFunctions.easeInOutCubic;
    let perc = 0

    function moveCircle() {
      count = count < 1 ? (count + 0.005) : 0;

      perc = countFunc(count) * 100 <= 100 ? countFunc(count) * 100 :  countFunc(count) * 100 - 100
      perc = perc >= 0 ? perc : 100 + perc
      if (perc === 0) {
        clearInterval(moveCircInterval);
        setTimeout(() => {
            moveCircInterval = setInterval(moveCircle, refreshRate);
        }, 5000);
    }

      var icons = line.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = perc + '%';

      line.set('icons', icons);
    }

    var moveCircInterval = setInterval(moveCircle, refreshRate);
  }
```

Please try it and let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
function animateCircle(line) {
  var remove = window.setInterval(function() {
    var count = 0;
    let refreshRate = 20;
    let countFunc = EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuint;
    let perc = 0
    var now, before = new Date();
    var move = window.setInterval(function() {
      now = new Date();
      var elapsedTime = (now.getTime() - before.getTime());
      var icons = line.get('icons');

      if (elapsedTime > refreshRate + 5000) {
        // reset if navigate away from tab
        count = 0.005
        window.clearInterval(move)
      } else {
        count = count < 1 ? (count + 0.005) : 0;
      }

      perc = countFunc(count) * 100 <= 100 ? countFunc(count) * 100 : countFunc(count) * 100 - 100
      perc = perc >= 0 ? perc : 100 + perc
      perc === 0 || perc === 100 ? (window.clearInterval(move)) : ''

      icons[0].icon.path = svgTrans(perc)
      icons[0].offset = perc + '%';

      line.set('icons', icons);
    }, refreshRate)

  }, 5000)
}
```

[here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehpot20j/30/)