# Canvas Taking too much time to move a picture up

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, lag

I am trying to move a image on `<canvas>` to jump.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ball Jump</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="./assets/ball.png" height="0px" width="0px" id="ball">
<br>


<br>
<canvas height="210px" width="350px" id="paper" onclick="play()"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
'use strict'
var paper = document.getElementById('paper');
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var brush = paper.getContext('2d');
brush.drawImage(dino, 0, 150, 70, 50);
var y = 150;
function play() {
up();
function up() {
if (y > 50) {
brush.clearRect(0, y-1, 70, y+50);
brush.drawImage(ball, 0, y, 70, 50);
y--;
}
else { clearInterval(jump); }
}
var jump = setInterval(up, 10);
function down() {
if (y < 150) {
brush.clearRect(0, y-1, 70, y+50);
brush.drawImage(ball, 0, y, 70, 50);
y++;
}
else { clearInterval(fall); }
}
var fall = setInterval(down, 10);
}
```

But the problem is that the ball is lagging and taking more time to go up, however it is coming down fine even if both functions are set to 10ms.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`

**Example**

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const image = new Image();
image.src = "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/50/50";

image.addEventListener("load", load);

function load(event) {
  loop();
}

let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let t = 0;
let r = 50;
const inc = Math.PI/90;

function loop() {
  const width = canvas.width;
  const height = canvas.height;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.drawImage(image, x, y, image.width, image.height);
  
  x = 100 + r * Math.cos(t);
  y = 100 + r * Math.sin(t);
  t = t + inc;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

```html
<canvas height="400px" width="400px" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes they should, but they should do it right. On a 240Hz monitor your animation will run 4x faster than on a 60Hz one. Use the timestamp to build a delta time to create a constant animation speed.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use multiple `setInterval` just one should do...
Here is an example:

```js
var paper = document.getElementById('paper');
var brush = paper.getContext('2d');
var y = 100;
var speed = 1;

function draw() {
  if ((y < 10) || (y > 150)) {
    speed *= -1
  }
  y += speed
  brush.clearRect(0, 0, 160, 300);
  brush.fillRect(10, y, 10, 10);
}

function play() {
  setInterval(draw, 10);
}

draw()
```

```html
<canvas height="160" width="300" id="paper" onclick="play()"></canvas>
```

In your code, both intervals are running simultaneously that could create the strange behavior you are seeing where the object is lagging and taking more time to go up but coming down is fine.

Instead of the two `setInterval` I introduced the variable `speed` that will determine the direction of the movement and we will "flip" it `speed *= -1` when the position exceeds our boundaries

... with this pattern in your canvas animation it's easy to transition to `requestAnimationFrame` if performance becomes critical, but for simple practice code like this, setInterval works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For animations running smoothly on the browser, you should really use a requestAnimationFrame loop instead of setInterval

checkout the example here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

here is why:
[Why is requestAnimationFrame better than setInterval or setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709923/why-is-requestanimationframe-better-than-setinterval-or-settimeout#:~:text=The%20question%20is%20most%20simply,or%20completely%20remove%20frame%20skips).