# setTimeout() Irregular Execution Behaviour

Tags: javascript, performance

Why `setTimeout` callback is not executing even after the desired delay time.

It is taking more time to execute based on the time to execute the other code of the program.

```js
console.time('CalculateExeutionTime');

console.log("Staring....");

setTimeout(() => {
   console.log("Inside setTimeout.");
}, 100);

console.log("Middle...");

let start = 0;
let end = 1000000000;
while(end > start){
  start++
}
console.log("End...");

console.timeEnd('CalculateExeutionTime')
```

Also when I set the time to execute the callback of `setTimeout` to **zero**, still it is not executing.

```js
console.time('CalculateExeutionTime');

console.log("Staring....");

setTimeout(() => {
   console.log("Inside setTimeout.");
}, 0);

console.log("Middle...");

let start = 0;
let end = 1000000000;
while(end > start){
  start++
}
console.log("End...");

console.timeEnd('CalculateExeutionTime')
```

Is there any way that makes sure the `setTimeout` execute at the after the desired time.

Comment: The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded and you're blocking this one thread with your `while()` loop -> working as expected

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#event_loop

Comment: prefer measurement by https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-measure-execution-times-in-javascript-9b56a650650d

Comment: @George That was I am looking why ``setTimeout()`` is not executing after the desired milliseconds.

Comment: If working with animations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709923/why-is-requestanimationframe-better-than-setinterval-or-settimeout

Comment: @Andreas Is there any way to run both parallelly, so that even when ``while()`` is executing the ``setTimeout()`` also execute

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish (because your example doesn't make that much sense in its current form)? And no. There's just one thread, and `while()` blocks it. You can use a `ServiceWorker` but then we're back at my question...

Comment: @NotABot don't use busy waits like this. It's usually a bad practice even in multi-threaded environments. What are you actually trying to do here? Because I suspect you don't have a loop that only keeps the application busy doing nothing in your code. If you want to have a game you need a game loop. If you have some sort of animation, then you can similarly progressively change it. The very broad problem doesn't have a singular solution other than "don't do that, work with the event loop". But that's not nearly specific enough.

Comment: Define and call function in one step 
`(function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Inside setTimeout.");
    }, 0);
})();`

Comment: See [setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) on MDN