# Framerate in HTML canvas ("Color Piano" app)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I would like to make a webpage with a "[piano roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_roll#In_digital_audio_workstations)", here's a rough visualization (without some planned customizations):

[image]

Basing it on [Color Piano](https://galactic.ink/piano/) might be promising because it allows uploading a MIDI file and plays the audio smoothly.

However, Color Piano doesn't move the piano roll smoothly **visually**. The distance that the bars travel is different in each frame, and/or the frame rate is low, and/or the duration of frames is inconsistent. You can see that if you look closely on [the original page](https://galactic.ink/piano/) (might depend on your hardware) or in [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoIje8pwd7s).

There are piano roll apps that run more smoothly (on the same hardware) using `canvas`, for example [Piano Roll from Chrome Music Lab](https://musiclab.chromeexperiments.com/Piano-Roll/). (But they don't directly allow to select an own MIDI file.)

Why is [Color Piano](https://galactic.ink/piano/) not smooth? Can it be easily salvaged by fixing some bug, or is it deeply based on some outdated technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to say with certainty without analyzing the source.

However, by profiling you might notice it is not a terribly intensive application:

[image: Firefox Profiler results showing a stable and low performance cost]

So I opened the `min/app.js` file in my text editor, and after some cursory searching, I noticed that it does attempt to polyfill `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame || (window.requestAnimationFrame = function () { return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (b, a) { window.setTimeout(b, 1E3 / 60) } }());
```

However, searching does not result in any other ocurrence of `requestAnimationFrame`, so I guess they're using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` for their render loop, which is [notoriously unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38709924/1045510).

So the most straighforward "fix" would be to replace the unspecialized timers with [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), and drive the animations using the timestamp provided in the callback.

This doesn't mean it's the *only* ocurrence of non-synchronized drawing, however, but it is certainly a good start.