# How to create delay in fractal drawing recursive function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, settimeout, delay

I am playing around with a fractal drawing recursive function encountered in [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/).

I want to set a delay for the drawing of each branch - for the purpose of visualizing the flow of branches/recursive calls as I tinker with this function and its parameters.

The way I have used `setTimeout` in the code below does not seem to work, and I am confused as to why.

I expected `cx.fillRect(...)` to draw a branch with each delay; rather then stack up in a queue, since there is no other code outside the `setTimeout` to wait for.

Below I have included first the working fractal drawing html/js code with no attempt at including a delay. The second snippet of code is my attempt at including a `setTimeout` delay.

My non-working attempt at using `setTimeout`:

```html
<canvas width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
  let cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

  function branch(length, angle, scale) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      cx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, length);
      if (length < 8) return;
      cx.save();
      cx.translate(0, length);
      cx.rotate(-angle);
      branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
      cx.rotate(2 * angle);
      branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
      cx.restore();
    }, 80);
  }
  cx.translate(300, 0);
  branch(60, 0.5, 0.8);
</script>
```

Working code without delay:

```html
<canvas width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
  let cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

  function branch(length, angle, scale) {
    cx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, length);
    if (length < 8) return;
    cx.save();
    cx.translate(0, length);
    cx.rotate(-angle);
    branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
    cx.rotate(2 * angle);
    branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
    cx.restore();
  }
  cx.translate(300, 0);
  branch(60, 0.5, 0.8);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attempt with `setTimeout` delays the first call, then spawns two recursive calls for its subtrees that have the same timeout, leading to them walking over each other, and so on down.

All recursive calls need to wait for the entire left subtree to complete drawing before moving on to the right one, which also needs to complete before the call can resolve and let the parent proceed to its next operation (right subtree or resolving). You can't have two different call frames messing with the same canvas stack at the same time.

I'd use promises to do this; this lets you manage the ordering of `setTimeout`s and set the desired delay with a `sleep` function, basically a promisified `setTimeout`.

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
);

const cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

async function branch(length, angle, scale) {
  cx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, length);

  if (length < 8) {
    return;
  }

  await sleep(50); // delay in ms, good to make into a parameter
  cx.save();
  cx.translate(0, length);
  cx.rotate(-angle);
  await branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
  cx.rotate(2 * angle);
  await branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
  cx.restore();
}

cx.translate(300, 0);
branch(60, 0.5, 0.8);
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

For comparison, here's how you could do it without promises using a callback that each child fires to signal to its parent that it's done, so the parent knows when to draw the next subtree or resolve:

```js
const cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

function branch(length, angle, scale, done) {
  cx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, length);

  if (length < 8) {
    done && done();
    return;
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    cx.save();
    cx.translate(0, length);
    cx.rotate(-angle);
    branch(length * scale, angle, scale, () => {
      cx.rotate(2 * angle);
      branch(length * scale, angle, scale, () => {
        cx.restore();
        done && done();
      });
    });    
  }, 50);
}

cx.translate(300, 0);
branch(60, 0.5, 0.8);
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Since you're doing an animation on canvas, you might consider using `requestAnimationFrame` to loop through a generator function that draws each frame. RAF offers [better-quality animations than `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709923/why-is-requestanimationframe-better-than-setinterval-or-settimeout).

```js
const cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

function *branch(length, angle, scale) {
  cx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, length);

  if (length < 8) {
    return;
  }

  yield;
  cx.save();
  cx.translate(0, length);
  cx.rotate(-angle);
  yield *branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
  cx.rotate(2 * angle);
  yield *branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
  cx.restore();
}

cx.translate(300, 0);
const branchGen = branch(60, 0.5, 0.8);
const speedMs = 50;
let lastTime = 0;
let done = false;

(function drawFrame(time) {
  !done && requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

  if (time && lastTime === 0) {
    lastTime = time;
  }
  else if (lastTime > 0 && time >= lastTime + speedMs) {
    ({done} = branchGen.next());
    lastTime += speedMs;
  }
})();
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```