# What is the correct way of chaining transitions with multiple elements in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I'm writing a small app using Svelte that presents a list of collapsible panels with text to the user, has them select a set of those panels, and, when the user clicks a button, groups these panels into another collapsible panel in a different list. Conceptually, it's the [deferred transitions tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/deferred-transitions) with an extra layer on one end.

I have [prepared a REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1fa407361427439d9658f4f3679c5390?version=3.59.1) so you can follow along. Replace the component in `App.svelte` to switch the implementations.

The `Original.svelte` component illustrates the problem:
I'm using Svelte's `crossfade` transition to send and receive, and everything looks great when the grouped panels are collapsed. Any open panel, however, will warp awkwardly to its closed state when sent between the lists, which I understand is an effect of `crossfade`. The solution is obvious: close the panels first, *then* send them over to their target.

My question is, now, what is the idiomatic/optimal way to do that in Svelte?

The `WithDelay.svelte` component shows my attempt using `delay` on the individual panel transitions based on whether a panel was open. As is evident, this delays the send/receive transitions but still warps the panels, no matter how long the delay is (try a second or longer).

My second intuition was to collect the panels to be moved in an intermediate list, close them, and finally use the transition events `on:outrostart`/`on:outroend` to finalize the move. However, the logic was too lengthy to be correct, requiring multiple helper functions and extra arrays to track the elements. Once multiple panels had their events fire simultaneously, everything just went haywire. Preventing race conditions turned out so complicated that I scrapped that attempt entirely.

My third attempt can be seen in `WithTimeout.svelte`, where I resorted to using `setTimeout` to delay the actual moving of elements after the panels have been closed. As expected, that works exactly how it should and should be used as a reference for what I want to achieve, but [using `setTimeout` just feels wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709923/why-is-requestanimationframe-better-than-setinterval-or-settimeout). Still, I feel like I should not need to implement my own `wait` function using `requestAnimationFrame` since Svelte itself seems to have no built-in function for that. Internally, it runs the transition in a [loop construct that uses `requestAnimationFrame`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/internal/transitions.ts#L201).

I'd go on with the timeout, but I would like to hear more experienced opinions before proceeding. I'm not even sure if my concerns are even justified. Maybe `requestAnimationFrame` only matters when doing actual transition stuff, and `setTimeout` is fine for assigning variables? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach could be to handle the closing inside the component via an exported function that returns a Promise that resolves when the out transition has ended.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8dd2f323585d4f08bd6f06bccdaa2534?version=3.59.1)

###### Panel.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">

    ...

    let resCb = () => {}

    export function close() {
        return new Promise(res => {
            if(open) {
                resCb = res
                open = false                
            }else {
                res()
            }
        })
    }

    function handleOutroEnd() {
        resCb()
    }

</script>

...

    {#if open}
    <div class="panel-content"
             in:slide|local="{{ duration: slideDuration }}"
             out:slide|local="{{ duration: slideDuration }}" 
             on:outroend={handleOutroEnd}            
             >
        <slot />
    </div>
    {/if}
```

(The `|local` flag added so that the slide transition doesn't play when the panels are added as slot to the `Panel` component for the group. Setting up an extra component for the group might be better.)

The function can be called on the component references that can be organised on an object with either the `panel.id` as key or a combination with the `group.key` (`crypto.randomUUID()` instead of `Symbol()`)

```
<script>
    
    ...

    const panelRefs = {}

    function panelRefKey(panel, group) {
        const key = (group.key ?? '') + panel.id
        return key
    }

</script>


                <Panel header={panel.header}
                             bind:selected={panel.selected}
                             bind:this={panelRefs[panel.id]}
                             >
                    {panel.content}
                </Panel>
            
                ...

                            <Panel header={panel.header}
                                         bind:this="{panelRefs[panelRefKey(panel, group)]}"
                                         onDelete={() => deletePanel(group, panel)}
                                >
                                {panel.content}
                            </Panel>
```

Since `close()` directly resolves if the component wasn't opened, tracking `bind:open` on the data/component is redundant and the function can simply be called on all component references before the data changes sides.

```js
    async function deleteGroup(group) {     
        const groupEntries = Object.entries(panelRefs).filter(([key, _]) => key.startsWith(group.key))
        const panelsToClose = groupEntries.filter(([_, panelRef])=> panelRef && panelRef.close).map(([_, panelRef]) => panelRef)

        await Promise.all(panelsToClose.map(panelRef => panelRef.close()))
        groupEntries.forEach(([key, _]) => delete panelRefs[key])

        ...
    }

    async function deletePanel(group, panel) {
        const key = panelRefKey(panel, group)
        await panelRefs[key].close()

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic! A solution using `outroend` was exactly what I was hoping for, as I was convinced this would be the way to go, but didn't think at all about using refs. I also had a similar construct to your `resCb` already, but then got just completely confused. Cheers!