# Moving a triangular ship in a canvas game in plain JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I am trying to move a triangle in the direction which the triangle is rotated by. When I press the key to move it, it doesn't move, but when I rotate it, its center of rotation shifts because of the key I pressed to move it previously.

I tried checking the formulas to determine the direction to move the triangle, but those seemed correct, and the translation point to rotate it is not moving based on those formulas.

Expected results: On click of the up arrow key, triangle moves in rotation angle direction.

Actual results: On click of up arrow key, triangle doesn't move in the direction, but if I click up arrow key, then left or right arrow key to rotate, triangle rotates away from center of rotation.

Here's my code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let ship_width = 20;
let ship_height = 20;
let angle = 0;
let ship_velocity_change = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}
//initial center coordinates of triangle
let ship_center = {
  x: 450,
  y: 300
};

let ship_points = [
  //coordinates for vertices of triangle
  {
    x: ship_center.x - ship_width / 2,
    y: ship_center.y +
      ship_height / 2
  },
  {
    x: ship_center.x + ship_width / 2,
    y: ship_center.y +
      ship_height / 2
  },
  {
    x: ship_center.x,
    y: ship_center.y - ship_height / 2
  }
];

function drawRect(x, y, width, height, color) {
  ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
}

//vertices for triangle as parameters
function drawTriangle(bottom_left, bottom_right, top, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(top.x, top.y);
  ctx.lineTo(bottom_left.x, bottom_left.y);
  ctx.lineTo(bottom_right.x, bottom_right.y);
  ctx.lineTo(top.x, top.y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.stroke();
}

//rotate triangle by an angle in degrees
function rotate(angle) {
  ctx.translate(ship_center.x, ship_center.y);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
  ctx.translate(-ship_center.x, -ship_center.y);
  drawTriangle(ship_points[2], ship_points[1], ship_points[0],
    "white");
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  //rate of degree change per 10 milliseconds
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    angle = -2;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
    //move triangle by direction of angle
    ship_center.x += Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle) * 5;
    ship_center.y += Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle) * 5;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
    angle = 2;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 39) {
    angle = 0;
  }
});

function game() {
  drawRect(0, 0, 900, 600, "black");
  rotate(angle);
}

let gameLoop = setInterval(game, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you possibly create a runnable snippet by clicking `edit` and then `[<>]` button? Or add a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so we can help debug and test your code

Comment: ok, working on it right now.

Comment: Done, feel free to run code snippet on full page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice attempt! This is one of those things that takes some experimentation to get right.

A few suggestions:

- Encapsulate all relevant data and functions for the ship in one object. This keeps things organized and easy to understand and will simplify your logic and reduce bugs significantly. This makes entity state and rendering functions much easier to manage.
- Avoid calling ship movement functions directly from the key event callback. Doing so can result in jerky, inconsistent behavior when the keyboard re-triggers. This callback should simply flip key flags, then let the event loop take care of calling the relevant functions based on those flags.
- Use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setInterval` for most animations.
- Something like `angle = 2;` is too rigid (this may have been temporary). We need to use `+=` here and introduce a velocity variable (and, ideally, acceleration too) for realistic rotation.
- `Math.PI / 180 * angle` for `Math` functions isn't strictly necessary. We can use `angle` directly in radians. If your game depends on setting angles with degrees, then you can add a conversion function.
- Use variables for acceleration and velocity if you want the movement to feel realistic. In the sketch below, I've added a few of these, but it's not a definitive approach and is intended to be tweaked to taste.

Here's a simple example of all of this in action. There is much room for improvement, but it should be a decent starter.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 200;

const kbd = {
  ArrowLeft: false, 
  ArrowUp: false, 
  ArrowRight: false
};

const ship = {
  angle: 0,
  color: "white",
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
  width: 10,
  height: 15,
  drag: 0.9,
  accSpeed: 0.04,
  rotSpeed: 0.012,
  rotv: 0,
  ax: 0,
  ay: 0,
  vx: 0,
  vy: 0,
  rotateLeft() {
    this.rotv -= this.rotSpeed;
  },
  rotateRight() {
    this.rotv += this.rotSpeed;
  },
  accelerate() {
    this.ax += this.accSpeed;
    this.ay += this.accSpeed;
  },
  move() {
    this.angle += this.rotv;
    this.rotv *= this.drag;
    this.vx += this.ax;
    this.vy += this.ay;
    this.ax *= this.drag;
    this.ay *= this.drag;
    this.vx *= this.drag;
    this.vy *= this.drag;
    this.x += Math.cos(this.angle) * this.vx;
    this.y += Math.sin(this.angle) * this.vy;
  },
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.height, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(-this.height, this.width);
    ctx.lineTo(-this.height, -this.width);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  }
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.code in kbd) {
    event.preventDefault();
    kbd[event.code] = true;
  }
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  if (event.code in kbd) {
    event.preventDefault();
    kbd[event.code] = false; 
  }
});

(function update() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  

  const shipActions = {
    ArrowLeft: "rotateLeft",
    ArrowUp: "accelerate",
    ArrowRight: "rotateRight",
  };

  for (const key in shipActions) {
    if (kbd[key]) {
      ship[shipActions[key]]();
    }
  }
  
  ship.move();
  ship.draw(ctx);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
})();
```